# invertibiliy of $I + {{{\partial ^2}} \over {\partial {x^2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, unbounded-operators

We consider the operator $$T=I + {{{\partial ^2}} \over {\partial {x^2}}}:{H^2}(0,L) \cap H_0^1(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)$$.
We shall prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if  $L = n\pi $.
and for this purpose we must show that $T$ is injective and surjective..
$T$ is Injective:
$${\rm{Ker\{ T\}  = \{  u}} \in {H^2}(0,L) \cap H_0^1(0,L),sinL = 0\}  = \{ 0\} $$  implies $L = n\pi $.
$T$ is surjectivr:
the solution can be calculated explicitly for all $f$ in  ${L^2}(0,L)$.
My question is: How can we prove the Only if statement.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is dense in ${H^2}(0,L) \cap H_0^1(0,L)$. Let 
$$u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$
be such that $Tu=0$. Then
$$ Tu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2})u_n\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}). $$
Thus $Tu=0$ if and only if $L=n\pi$ for some $n$ and then $\ker(T)=\text{span}\{\sin(x)\}$. Thus if $L\neq n\pi$ for any $n$, $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you sir..but  L=n pi  for all n  ?

Comment: If $L=n\pi$ for some $n$, then $T$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers sir. But i still perplexed...if Tu=0  then ker(T)=0..the operator is invertible...is that correct ?

Comment: See the new editing.

Comment: Ok sir. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $L=\pi,2\pi,3\pi,\cdots$, then $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is in $\mathcal{D}(T)$ because $f(0)=f(L)=0$, and $Tf=0$. So $T$ invertible only if $L \ne \pi,2\pi,3\pi$.

Conversely, if $L\ne \pi,2\pi,3\pi$, and if $g\in L^2$, then you can write down a solution $f\in\mathcal{D}(T)$ of $Tf=g$, and the solution is unique because $\mathcal{N}(T)=\{0\}$.